# Asp.Net WebAPI WebSockets in self host mode not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, self-host-webapi

basically I'm trying to do web-sockets in `webapi` in a self-host manner.

Here's an example:

```
class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage SomeAction()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new SomeSocketHandler());
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `HttpContext.Current` is always null.
It **only** exists when hosting through IIS.

My question is how can I do self-hosted web sockets using `webapi` if I can't get the current context.

Thanks.